# What is this Eclipselink error and how to solve it?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Here is the relevant stacktrace:

```
[EL Warning]: 2017-05-11 16:35:34.18--ServerSession(4115088)--Exception [EclipseLink-32] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Trying to set value [0] for instance variable [EmpInd] of type [char] in the object.  The specified object is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field, or an unwrapping conversion has failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set char field com.MyProj.entity.EmployeeTask.empInd to java.lang.Integer
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[EmpInd-->EMPLOYEE_TASK.EMP_IND]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.MyProj.entity.EmployeeTask --> [DatabaseTable(EMPLOYEE_TASK)])

at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.illegalArgumentWhileSettingValueThruInstanceVariableAccessor(DescriptorException.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.setAttributeValueInObject(InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.setAttributeValueInObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1259)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:958)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:2322)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.valueFromRowInternal(OneToOneMapping.java:1563)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1534)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:958)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:681)
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is this phrase:

```
Can not set char field com.MyProj.entity.EmployeeTask.empInd to java.lang.Integer Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[EmpInd-->EMPLOYEE_TASK.EMP_IND] Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.MyProj.entity.EmployeeTask --> [DatabaseTable(EMPLOYEE_TASK)])
```

The database field `EMPLOYEE_TASK.EMP_IND` is an integer while the Java field `com.MyProj.entity.EmployeeTask.empInd` is a `char`. EclipseLink is unable to convert the integer returned from the database into a `char` so it can be set in your `EmployeeTask` object.